# Specify methods versus properties in a vue-bootstrap b-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have an array of Dates, and I want to display the dates to the user in a b-select dropdown and to customize the date format being displayed.  The b-select allows a text-field to be used, but I want a way to select a method on the object instead of a property.

Do I need to create an intermediate structure to serve as the options for the b-select?

Comment: please add some code to us with your datas and so on.. otherwise it's difficult to help you out because we don't know your strucutre and how your code is builded.. Thank You!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.